# Wxpython: How to use different border color for Search box

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am using `wx.SearchCtrl` and I need a red border around the search field. In the documentation, I could not find anything to do this easily. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the border colour directly, but you could use the usual trick with making this search control a child of `wx.Panel` with the background colour you want and make it just a few pixels smaller than its parent.